# How password can be prompted in percona xtrabackup

Tags: mysql, percona, backup, xtrabackup

How password can be prompted while using percona xtrabackup.--ask-pass option is not working with xtrabackup. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I donot think there is --ask-pass in xtrabackup! You might want to write a wrapper shell script which will

`echo enter mysql password
read -s pw`

and then pass it as `--password=$pw`.